# CoreDataBooks Example Saving Conditions

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, core-data

I have based a large portion of CoreData functionality n my app on the CoreDataBooks example by Apple. There is a specific attribute, for me the 'name', that must be filled in before saving is possible.

How can I alter the code to only allow saving under certain circumstances? Such as only saveable when that name field is not empty?

Any help much appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is an "optional" option for your entity attribute. First select the attribute then in the side bar un-check optional, see image below. Also there is a validation option where you can define: min. and max. lengths, and default values.

[image]

Comment: Oh darn, theres a problem with this. I can enter text then delete it again and it enables the save button and doesn't disable it again if the text is deleted. How can I do a check to see if there is any text and then if needed programatically change this attribute?

Comment: Check out the `validate...` family of methods on [NSManagedObject](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/CoreDataFramework/Classes/NSManagedObject_Class/Reference/NSManagedObject.html)

Comment: You can always check if a textField has text by checking the length. if textField.text.length > 0; SAVE , else set attribute to your default value, SAVE

Comment: Just been playing around, seems simply adding a minimum length of 1 character stops the save button bugging out and allowing save if you enter and delete all characters again. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

1. Click on the `xcdatamodeld` file
2. Select the `entity` where you want to apply this constraint
3. Select the `attribute` you want to make mandatory

   - ensure the `Utilities` panel of xcode is open
4. Uncheck the `Optional` check box